# How to check condition for shell script same as javascript

Tags: bash, shell

I tried check shell script condition for same as javascript but is this not working

**javascript**

```
const data = "string";
if (data) {
   console.log("condition true");
}
```

**shell script**

```
# /bin/bash

data="string"
name=test
age=24

if($data); then
echo "condition satisfied"
fi

if [ "$data" && "$name" && "$age" ]; then
    echo "condition satisfied"
fi
```

[check here](https://repl.it/repls/KeenHighlevelArchitect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `test` command, usually written as `[`.

```
#!/bin/bash

data="string"
if [ -n "$data" ]; then
    echo "condition satisfied"
fi
```

For multiple conditions use `&&` between the tests.

```
if [ -n "$data" ] && [ -n "$name" ] && [ -n "$age" ]
```

Comment: Note that if the string is literally just the word `string`, you don't need the double quotes; you only need those if the value has spaces or certain other special characters in it (in which case single quotes would be safer). Since you tagged this `bash`, note that you can also remove the double quotes around `$data` if you use double `[[`...`]]`instead of single `[`...`]`. That doesn't work in all sh-compatible shells and is not part of the POSIX spec for such, though.

Comment: Thanks barmar, but I have another doubt is how check multiple condition in single condition help for us

Comment: The literal assignment is presumably just an example, in a real application the variable would be set dynamically. And I prefer to quote variables all the time, it's easier than trying to remember when they can be omitted. @MarkReed

Comment: @SaranRaj I think you need to learn shell scripting, this isn't a programming school.

Comment: Yes barmar I am beginner for this.

Comment: Use shellcheck.net to check the syntax of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to see the equivalent to *console log* printed to stdout, the following will do:

```
[ "$data" ] && echo "condition satisfied"
```

or equivalently

```
test "$data" && echo "condition satisfied"
```

(the double quotes are needed for the case `data` contains a space), or, provided you have bash (since you tagged the question for *bash* and for *shell*),

```
[[ $data ]] && echo "condition satisfied"
```

Here the quotes are not needed.

All variants test whether the variable data contains a non-empty string, and if this is the case, it prints the message.

This is of course **not** exactly the same as `if(data)` in JavaScript, because in JavaScript, if data had the value 0, the condition would be considered **false**. You can emulate this behvaviour in shell too, but it gets more cumbersome.